# Cannot load ado.net MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, .net-4.0, ado.net, dbproviderfactories

Under C#, framework 4.5.
I installed Mysql connector 6.7.4.

If I try to load dynamically the dll with

```
DbProviderFactory fac = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("MySql.Data.MySqlClient");
```

I get : **Failed to find or load the registered .Net Framework Data Provider.**

- I added in app.config the mysql (I even can list it with a GetFactoryClasses() !)
- I tried to put the MySQL assembly in GAC

Nothing works :(

Comment: Did you install it from [here](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql-installer-for-windows.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a bug with the current provider. I had the same issue. You should use version 6.6.6, it worked for me.
Here's a description for the bug [register the provider in machine.config](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=69760)

Comment: In fact, I get the same behaviour with the Sybase. I added the DbProvider in app.config. If I list the driver I can see it. But same error when I run the GetFactory. (In the meantime, System.data.SqlClient from SqlServer works perfectly !??)

Comment: This is interesting. Are you listing the providers and then call GetFactory method? If so, the last should not crash if the first succeded. GetFactoryClasses method caches the dataSet with all the factories, so GetFactory should use the same set as the previous call. Maybe something else bad happens along the way but the error is not updated. What's wrong with using a previous, stable version of MySql connector?

Comment: Very interesting indeed. In fact before using the 6.6.6, I tried with another driver. I installed Sybase ASE 12.5 => Same behaviour. I can call them "statically", with Assembly.LoadFrom/Activator. but not with DbProviderFactory. (It seems that it happens with all "fake providers")

Comment: Yes, only with fake. System.Data.OracleClient and System.Data.SqlClient work perfectly. Did I miss something ?

Comment: You're right, the 6.6.6 version works perfectly !! Now I need to understand why Sybase version failed :(

Comment: Yeah, maybe the two aren't related. Or maybe all the mySql trials ruined something. Maybe test it on a clean machine. Either way, let us know if you have any more information.